# Difference between method definition and object's function property

Tags: javascript

This my code

```
const x = {
    a() {
      console.log("a");
    },
    b: function() {
      console.log("b");
    },

};
```

Is there a difference between `a` & `b` functions?

I read somewhere, that the `a() {}` way of creating methods is shorter, but can bring a number of problems.

Use it only in those cases when you are sure that you will never use recursion or pass a function to events handlers.

Is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real difference is that `a` is defined as a [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions), meaning that it can't be instantiated with `new`:

```js
const x = {
  a() {
  },
  b: function() {
  }
};

new x.b();


new x.a();
```

A trivial difference is that, in sloppy mode, the method has the `arguments` and `caller` properties on its *internal prototype*, whereas the function has those properties on the function object itself:

```js
const x = {
  a() {
  },
  b: function() {
  }
};

console.log(x.a.hasOwnProperty('arguments'), x.a.hasOwnProperty('caller'));
console.log(x.b.hasOwnProperty('arguments'), x.b.hasOwnProperty('caller'));
```

Accessing these properties is forbidden in strict mode, and in method definitions. They are deprecated.

Comment: I read somewhere. This. `a() {} This method of creating methods is shorter, but can bring a number of problems. Use it only in those cases when you are sure that you will never use recursion or pass a function to events handlers.`Can't remember where.And is this true?

Comment: No, I've never heard of that. It might be a good warning for *some* sort of code, but it's irrelevant to the code here - methods have no issues with recursion or event handlers. (though, just like with a `function`, if using an event handler, make sure to use the proper calling context - you may need to `.bind` or something)

Comment: there are still differences super won't work
b: function () {}